# How to get color palette

Tags: php, c++, colors, color-palette

How can i get color palettes of uploaded in my website?

Comment: try photoshop instead you can download a free trial for 30 days on the adobe website

Comment: I want to it automatically, I cannot do it one by one manually

Comment: try imagetruecolortopalette() from php's GD lib

Comment: What is your goal? Why are you interested in the palette but not the image itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find that there is no way getting them without using C++ you can use GDI+ in C++. There is Bitmap or Image classes in it. You just need to get the pixels, go through them and get the RGB. If I understand your question.